# AWS EC2: What is difference between 0.0.0.0/0 Vs ::/0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Part of EC2 setup, in the configuration of Security Group, I am trying to add the rule for HTTP/HTTPS for allowing internet traffic. Isn't enough to add CIDR notation 0.0.0.0/0? Do we need both 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0?

Comment: one is ipv4, the other is ipv6. If you only expect ipv4 traffic, you probably only need 0.0.0.0. so... maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::` is a shorthand for the IPv6 address of `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`. You need it allow IPv6 communication. For more information see [Getting Started with IPv6 for Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/get-started-ipv6.html#get-started-ipv6-sg)
.